# What's a good reference for the continuity of the number of zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, roots

What is a good reference for the following statement, or something that easily implies it?

For all sequences $\:\langle\:f_0,f_1,f_2,f_3,...\rangle\:$ of (complex) analytic functions $\:\:f_n : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}\:$,

for all complex analytic functions $\:\:f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}\:$, $\:$ if $\:\:f(0) = 0\:$ and $\:f$ is not identically zero

and $\:\langle\:f_0,f_1,f_2,f_3,...\rangle\:$ converges uniformly to $\:f$ on the unit disk,

then for sufficiently large $n$, $\:f_n$ has a zero in the unit disk.

I saw this proved back in complex analysis and could probably re-prove it from

Cauchy's integral formula and the argument principle, but I feel that there should

be some reference that can be used, even though I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: It's an easy consequence of the minimum modulus principle, also of Rouché's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29); the Wikipedia page has references.